# How to set targetSdkVersion 33 in ionic application?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework, ionic6, targetsdkversion

I have created an ionic application using ionic 6 and it works fine. I would like to upload this app to the Google Play Store. I added targetSdkVersion version 33 to the config.xml file based on the Play Store documents. `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />` After adding this line, I was unable to create the Android build.

When I create a build, I get an error message

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.plugins.MavenPlugin'.
        This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Comment: if you use cordova just update to cordova-android 11.

https://cordova.apache.org/news/2023/01/16/cordova-cli-11.1.0-release.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the API version as follows in Android studio.

1. Go to Project Structure
2. Click on modules
3. Change values
4. Apply and click OK